# Delay function affecting active class - one page scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, settimeout

I have a one Page site with scrolling Nav. When I click a link it adds an active class to the button but also a delay for the scroll effect.

This delay also stops the active class from immediately showing

I've tried to put them in separate functions and with different selectors but I can't seem to take the delay off the active class.

```
$("a").on('click', function (event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
        $('.navbar a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        // Prevent default anchor click behavior
        event.preventDefault();

        // Store hash
        var hash = this.hash;

        // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
        // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 800, function () {
            // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
            window.location.hash = hash;
        });
    } // End if
});
```

This gives a delay to the active class on Desktop - which I can live with.
But on mobile it doesn't show the active class until the dom is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

So the Dom Click showing active class is because Bootstrap auto adds a background on `a:hover` or `a:focus` - requiring a dom click to apply the active background color.

However I still don't know how to stop the delay of the scroll affecting the delay of the active class.